# express-subdomain won't render views, falls through to main domain

Tags: express, subdomain

I'm using express-subdomain 1.0.5 with express 4 to route a subdomain for my site. I have localhosts set up and that's working fine. In my main application.js, I have this:

```
//views
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//subdomains
var developerRoutes = require('./developerRoutes');
app.use(subdomain('test-developer', developerRoutes));

// main routes 
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use(routes);
```

The developerRoutes file looks like this:

```
var developer = require('../src/developer');
var devRouter = require('express').Router();

devRouter.get('/', developer.developerHome);

module.exports = devRouter;
```

and developer looks like this (I expect to have ~10 routes so I'm using a separate file):

```
exports.developerHome = function(req, res) {
    console.log('hi developer got here') //this fires, so I know this route is being called
    res.render('developerHome', {
        data: {
            testData: 'hi'
        }
    });
}
```

When I try test-developer.localhost.dev, it 404s (and developerHome.ejs exists). When I try any other route that exists for the main domain but is not present in the developer routes file (e.g. test-developer.localhost.dev/about), it renders the main view. If I try a plain `res.send('hi!');` in developer.js, that renders fine.

Is there some ordering of the middleware that I'm missing? I've tried putting the view engine lines both before and after the main and subdomain lines, with no change. Is there any way to make the subdomain routes fall through to the express errorhandling middleware instead of (as it seems) the main routes?

**Editing to add** -- If I force status and send HTML as below it works, but why?

```
exports.developerHome = function(req, res) {
    console.log('hi developer got here')
    res.render('developer/developerHome', 
      {data:
        {
            testData: 'hi'
        }
            },
      function(err, html){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        res.status(200).send(html);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps in the second answer to your own question you,changed your path in the `res.render` from `developerHome` to `developer/developerHome` thats why it works....

Comment: Unfortunately, that wasn't the case ... I was just tidying the views directory. 

The render function doesn't work in either case without a res.send() included.